# Cannot Enter Any Input When Using npm prompts

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, input

I've encounter a very strange problem after installing nmp prompts. I'm trying to run nmp prompts example code, but can't enter any input at all. When I run the code the underscore in the input field blinks for a few second, then the cursor jumps to the next line of the terminal and I can't click into the input field to write anything.

[image]

[image]

Tried running it in cmd and in VSC terminal. Here is the code itself:

```
const prompts = require('prompts');

(async () => {
  const response = await prompts({
    type: 'number',
    name: 'value',
    message: 'How old are you?',
    validate: (value: number) => value < 18 ? `Nightclub is 18+ only` : true
  });

  console.log(response); // => { value: 24 }
})();
```

Only thing I changed was adding type 'number' to 'value'

Answer (score 0):

Basically the fault lies within the '|' separator. Input works as it should if you write it in two lines like:

```
tsc index.ts
node index.js
```

or use a separator '&&' instead of '|', like this:

```
tsc index.ts && node index.js
```